# Why selecting text in the TextBlock throws exception in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

The following code snippet throws a System Exception.

```
TextBlock selectionText = new TextBlock();                        
                    selectionText.IsTextSelectionEnabled = true;                        
                    selectionText.Text = "Hello world";                        
                    selectionText.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(global::Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0));
                    selectionText.SelectAll();
```

What is wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: And, the exception is....?

Comment: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
it is thrown at the call of SelectAll() method

Comment: I Can't able to set the IsTextSelectionEnabled in my WPF TextBlock. Kindly assist me how to set the Property to TRUE...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure `selectionText` is displayed before calling `SelectAll()` on it, i.e. you should add it to a panel inside your current page:

```
TextBlock selectionText = new TextBlock();
selectionText.IsTextSelectionEnabled = true;
selectionText.Text = "Hello world";
selectionText.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(global::Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0));
MainPanel.Children.Add(selectionText);
Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, selectionText.SelectAll);
```

Notice two changes:

- The call to `MainPanel.Children.Add()` where `MainPanel` is the name of a panel control on your page.
- `selectionText.SelectAll()` called via `Dispatcher` to make sure `selectionText` is actually added to the panel before the call executes.

Comment: It really servers the purpose, the whole text could be acquired from the selectionText.SelecteText but the text in the TextBlock is not highlighted... I need to highlight that text...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the forgrund color

```
Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0)
```

The first number desides the level of "Alpha" which means transparancy. Windows RT may not be able to handel that.

Try this instead

```
Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0, 0)
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is no problem with the colorspace and the problem is in the text selection..